# Проблемы с вложенными страницами в modx evo

Tags: modx

Дизайнером были переделаны страницы товаров http://www.litomarket.ru/catalog/suxie-smesi/kleevie-smesi/cementnie-klei/litostone-k99-belyij так чтобы вкладки переключались без перезагрузки страницы, но возникла проблема: 
http://www.litomarket.ru/catalog/suxie-smesi/kleevie-smesi/cementnie-klei/litostone-k99-belyij/instr.html ссылки на эти страницы некорректно отображаются.
Подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением к якорной ссылке [~id~] текущего документа.
Была такая же проблема, помогло.

Comment: не совсем понял как и где, можете показать пример?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/285yon
Вот тут: <a href="#instr">Инструкции</a> должно быть так:
<a href="[~id текущей страницы~]#instr">Инструкции</a>

id текущей страницы - http://www.litomarket.ru/catalog/suxie-smesi/kleevie-smesi/cementnie-klei/litostone-k99-belyij

Comment: А где это можно изменить? в шаблоне страницы? и каким образом это повлияет на sitemap?

Comment: А где у вас прописан код этих табов?
На sitemap не влияет, это же просто якорная ссылка на странице.

Comment: проблема как раз в sitemap, ссылки на постраницы генерируются неверно

Comment: можно конкретно узнать где тут:
http://www.litomarket.ru/sitemap.xml
http://www.litomarket.ru/sitemap.html
проблема?

Comment: http://www.litomarket.ru/catalog/suxie-smesi/kleevie-smesi/cementnie-klei/litostone-k99-belyij/instr.html
об этом же написано в вопросе